# How can i rotate the camera with the mouse around the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now it's rotating in space i can rotate the camera around but not around the player. I want the camera to be rotating only around the player.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedH = 2.0f;
    public float speedV = 2.0f;
    private float yaw = 0.0f;
    private float pitch = 0.0f;

    public Transform playerTransform;
    public Transform mainCameraTransform = null;
    private Vector3 cameraOffset = Vector3.zero;
    public float turnSpeed = 3;

    void Start()
    {
        mainCameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        //Get camera-player Transform Offset that will be used to move the camera 
        cameraOffset = mainCameraTransform.position - playerTransform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Move the camera to the position of the playerTransform with the offset that was saved in the begining
        mainCameraTransform.position = playerTransform.position + cameraOffset;

        yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        mainCameraTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

I'm using now eulerAngles for the rotation.

Comment: Create an object that is centered on the player, then add the camera as a child to that object. Then rotating the camera around the player would be as simple as changing the parent object's local rotation.

Comment: @Abion47 i tried: same as in my script but changed the line from: mainCameraTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f); To transform.parent.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f); but it's still rotating the camera not the empty GameObject i placed in the thirdpersoncontroller center. The script is attached to the Main Camera that is child of the GameObject.

Comment: Attach it to the object itself. With this approach, the object is what the mouse will be actually controlling, while the camera just goes along for the ride.

Comment: I found how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you need to create a parent object for the camera, and rotate that object instead of the camera. Try this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedH = 2.0f;
    public float speedV = 2.0f;
    private float yaw = 0.0f;
    private float pitch = 0.0f;

    public Transform playerTransform;
    public Transform mainCameraTransform = null;
    private Vector3 cameraOffset = Vector3.zero;
    public float turnSpeed = 3;

    // Create a camera parent object
    GameObject cameraParent;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraParent = new GameObject();
        mainCameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        //Get camera-player Transform Offset that will be used to move the camera 
        cameraOffset = mainCameraTransform.position - playerTransform.position;

        // Position the camera parent to the player and add the camera as a child
        cameraParent.transform.position = playerTransform.position;
        mainCameraTransform.parent = cameraParent.transform;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Move the camera to the position of the playerTransform with the offset that was saved in the begining
        //mainCameraTransform.position = playerTransform.position + cameraOffset;

        yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        // Rotate the camera parent instead of the camera
        cameraParent.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Found how to do it. With adding a cube to the center of player. Working great. I also added zoom in out.

Comment: @Abion47 I have edited the code so that the cameraParent is instantiated within the Start method, and also removed the line of code that was changing the camera position, and it now works perfectly. I don't understand your statement that the object needs to be created in the project view. Are you familiar with the idea of creating GameObjects within code?